# How to Inject Multiple Extension Values in JUnit 5 with ParameterResolver

Tags: android, kotlin, junit, android-testing, junit5

## How may multiple values be injected into the test using the ParameterResolver pattern?

It seems that only one return value may be defined.

Currently, `getStore` saves an extension value which is injected as a parameter using `ParameterResolver`. In this example, it is a `TestCoroutineDispatcher`  injected to manage the Coroutine lifecycle in a local JUnit test. **What about if a second value needs to be injected from the same extension?**

### Implementation

*Test.kt*

```
@ExtendWith(LifecycleExtensions::class)
// The TestCoroutineDispatcher is injected here as a parameter.
class FeedLoadContentTests(val testDispatcher: TestCoroutineDispatcher) {

    private val contentViewModel = ContentViewModel()
    private fun FeedLoad() = feedLoadTestCases()

    @ParameterizedTest
    @MethodSource("FeedLoad")
    fun `Feed Load`(test: FeedLoadContentTest) = testDispatcher.runBlockingTest {
        // Some testing done here.
    }
}
```

*Extension.kt*

```
class LifecycleExtensions : BeforeAllCallback, AfterAllCallback, BeforeEachCallback,
        AfterEachCallback, ParameterResolver {
    ...

    override fun beforeEach(context: ExtensionContext?) {
        // Set Coroutine Dispatcher.
        Dispatchers.setMain(context?.getStore(STORE_NAMESPACE)
                ?.get(STORE_KEY, TestCoroutineDispatcher::class.java)!!)

        ...
    }

    override fun afterEach(context: ExtensionContext?) {
        // Reset Coroutine Dispatcher.
        Dispatchers.resetMain()
        context?.getStore(STORE_NAMESPACE)
                ?.get(STORE_KEY, TestCoroutineDispatcher::class.java)!!.cleanupTestCoroutines()

        ...
    }

    override fun supportsParameter(parameterContext: ParameterContext?,
                                   extensionContext: ExtensionContext?) =
            parameterContext?.parameter?.type == TestCoroutineDispatcher::class.java

    override fun resolveParameter(parameterContext: ParameterContext?,
                                  extensionContext: ExtensionContext?) =
            TestCoroutineDispatcher().apply {
                extensionContext?.getStore(STORE_NAMESPACE)?.put(STORE_KEY, this)
            }
}
```

Comment: A `ParameterResolver` can be implemented to support any number of parameters of any type. What do you mean exactly by a "second value"?

Comment: @Slaw, I'm referring to injecting multiple values from the overrode methods `supportsParameter` and `resolveParameter`. In the case above, a `TestCoroutineDispatcher` is injected into the test. However, I'm researching how to to inject an additional value from the same `LifecycleExtensions` class. For instance, if I wanted to also inject a shared ViewModel used across tests.

Comment: Well, both `#supportsParameter` and `#resolveParameter` is invoked _for each parameter in the method_. So you currently have a test to see if the parameter type is `TestCoroutineDispatcher` which means you can add a test for the shared `ViewModel` type. Then resolve the correct parameter based on the type. If you want to share the `ViewModel` across multiple tests then you can store a reference to it in the parent/root `ExtensionContext.Store`.

Comment: I've implemented your strategy in the answer below @Slaw. Please upvote the question and answer if correct in order to help others discover the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for the insight [@Slaw](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6395627/slaw)!

> Well, both #supportsParameter and #resolveParameter is invoked for each parameter in the method. So you currently have a test to see if the parameter type is TestCoroutineDispatcher which means you can add a test for the shared ViewModel type. Then resolve the correct parameter based on the type. If you want to share the ViewModel across multiple tests then you can store a reference to it in the parent/root ExtensionContext.Store.

*Test.kt*

```
@ExtendWith(LifecycleExtensions::class)
// The TestCoroutineDispatcher is injected here as a parameter.
class FeedLoadContentTests(val testDispatcher: TestCoroutineDispatcher, val contentViewModel: ContentViewModel) {

    private fun FeedLoad() = feedLoadTestCases()

    @ParameterizedTest
    @MethodSource("FeedLoad")
    // Injected testDispatcher used here.
    fun `Feed Load`(test: FeedLoadContentTest) = testDispatcher.runBlockingTest {
        // Some testing done here.
        // Injected contentViewModel used here.
    }
}
```

*Extension.kt*

```
class LifecycleExtensions : BeforeAllCallback, AfterAllCallback, BeforeEachCallback,
        AfterEachCallback, ParameterResolver {

    override fun beforeEach(context: ExtensionContext?) {
        // Set Coroutine Dispatcher.
        Dispatchers.setMain(context?.root
                ?.getStore(TEST_COROUTINE_DISPATCHER_NAMESPACE)
                ?.get(TEST_COROUTINE_DISPATCHER_KEY, TestCoroutineDispatcher::class.java)!!)

        // Set ViewModel
        context?.root
                ?.getStore(VIEWMODEL_NAMESPACE)
                ?.get(CONTENT_VIEWMODEL_KEY, ContentViewModel::class.java)!!

        // Set LiveData Executor.
        ArchTaskExecutor.getInstance().setDelegate(object : TaskExecutor() {
            override fun executeOnDiskIO(runnable: Runnable) = runnable.run()
            override fun postToMainThread(runnable: Runnable) = runnable.run()
            override fun isMainThread(): Boolean = true
        })
    }

    override fun afterEach(context: ExtensionContext?) {
        // Reset Coroutine Dispatcher.
        Dispatchers.resetMain()
        context?.root
                ?.getStore(TEST_COROUTINE_DISPATCHER_NAMESPACE)
                ?.get(TEST_COROUTINE_DISPATCHER_KEY, TestCoroutineDispatcher::class.java)!!
                .cleanupTestCoroutines()

        // Clear LiveData Executor
        ArchTaskExecutor.getInstance().setDelegate(null)
    }

    override fun resolveParameter(parameterContext: ParameterContext?,
                                  extensionContext: ExtensionContext?) =
            if (parameterContext?.parameter?.type == TestCoroutineDispatcher::class.java)
                getTestCoroutineDispatcher(extensionContext).let { dipatcher ->
                    if (dipatcher == null) saveAndReturnTestCoroutineDispatcher(extensionContext)
                    else dipatcher
                }
            else getViewModel(extensionContext).let { viewModel ->
                if (viewModel == null) saveAndReturnContentViewModel(extensionContext)
                else viewModel
            }

    private fun getTestCoroutineDispatcher(context: ExtensionContext?) = context?.root
            ?.getStore(TEST_COROUTINE_DISPATCHER_NAMESPACE)
            ?.get(TEST_COROUTINE_DISPATCHER_KEY, TestCoroutineDispatcher::class.java)

    private fun saveAndReturnTestCoroutineDispatcher(extensionContext: ExtensionContext?) =
            TestCoroutineDispatcher().apply {
                extensionContext?.root
                        ?.getStore(TEST_COROUTINE_DISPATCHER_NAMESPACE)
                        ?.put(TEST_COROUTINE_DISPATCHER_KEY, this)
            }

    private fun getViewModel(context: ExtensionContext?) = context?.root
            ?.getStore(VIEWMODEL_NAMESPACE)
            ?.get(CONTENT_VIEWMODEL_KEY, ContentViewModel::class.java)

    private fun saveAndReturnContentViewModel(extensionContext: ExtensionContext?) =
            ContentViewModel().apply {
                extensionContext?.root
                        ?.getStore(VIEWMODEL_NAMESPACE)
                        ?.put(CONTENT_VIEWMODEL_KEY, ContentViewModel())
            }
}
```

Comment: If I understood you correctly, you want to share the same `ContentViewModel` instance between multiple test methods. Right now your `#resolveParameter` implementation will create a new instance and then replace the old instance, if any, that was already in the `Store`. If your goal really is to share the same `ContentViewModel` instance then you need to check if an instance is already in the `Store` and, if it exists, use that instance.

Comment: Great catch @Slaw! I've refactored the answer above to check if an instance already exists. If so, it uses the object from `store`, if not, it creates and stores a new one.